# Kial nomiĝas la pilko en futbalo 'piedpilko', kaj ne futbalpilko?

Tags: history

Mi komprenas kial futbalo estas pli klara ol piedpilko, sed tio ĉi ne havas sencon por mi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably for the same reason that *korbopilko* is a basketball: it is more descriptive. With *piedpilko* you know it's a ball related to kicking by foot, and you know that even if you don't know the game of football. Add to that the confusion between American football and non-American football (what the Americans call *soccer*), and a *futbalpilko* could either be a [rugby ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_ball) (egg-shape) or a [round football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_(ball)).

Another reason could be that there is a semantic duplication: *futbalo* already contains *-bal-*, which is what *pilko* means. So it's literally a 'football ball'.

As a general rule it seems good to avoid anything culture specific. And a reference to football assumes knowledge that is not necessary with the word *piedpilko*. So be explicit, even it you perhaps lose some elegance of expression in the process.

(Apologies for not replying in Esperanto -- I am out of practice)

Answer (score 1):

"Futbalo" estas internacia vorto (parto de Esperanto pro la 15-a regulo.)

Piedpilko estas kunmetaĵo (parto de Esperanto pro la sistemo de vortfarado.)

Ne eblas kunmeti "futbal-" kaj "pilko" por fari "futbalpilko" sed ja eblas diri "futbala pilko" laŭ la jena modelo

- Mi ŝatis ludi futbalon per tenisa pilko,

Answer (score 1):

*Futbalpilko* estas ĝusta Esperanta vorto, kaj ne estas regulo, kiu malpermesas kunmeti radikon de internacia vorto kun alia radiko. Sed ŝajnas, ke la parolantaro decidis favore al *piedpilko*, por nomi la pilkon. Io simila estas observebla okaze de Tvitero: La uzantoj nomas la servon *Tvitero*, la mesaĝojn *pepoj* kaj la tviteradon *pepado*.

Comment: Viaj ekzemploj ŝajnas eraraj al mi. Mi multe uzas Twitter, kaj ĉi tie, oni plej ofte ne ŝanĝas la nomon (oni konservas "Twitter"), kaj oni uzas "pepaĵon" por mesaĝo.

Comment: Efektive, en mia respondo mi indikis ke ne eblas kunmeti "futbal-" kaj "pilko" por fari "futbalpilko", sed mi neniel asertis ke temas pri "malpermesas kunmeti radikon de internacia vorto kun alia radiko". Temas pri la reguloj de Esperanta vortfarado. Se ni volas priskribi pilkon, ni uzu adjektivon. Golfa pilko, tenisa pilko, futbala pilko. Tiuj estas la normalaj esprimoj.